# How to draw a simple bar chart where each bar is of different color?

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

Dimple's website shows an example[1] of a simple bar chart where both,`x`values and `y` values come from two variables:

```
[{x:<height val>, y:<bar location>},
{x:<height val>, y:<bar location>},
{x:<height val>, y:<bar location>},
{x:<height val>, y:<bar location>}]
```

This chart displays one bar for each element in the array and the location and height are described by that element. This seems to assume that there will be a large number of bars and there doesn't seem to be a way of giving different color to each bar (also different entry in the legend).

My data looks more like this:

```
{jimmy:26, tommy:34, jenny:54, bobby:12}
```

I'd like to display a chart with four bars, each bar with a different color. I'd like to be able to add a legend where the color corresponds to the name.

How can I do this? I've messed around with adding a non-null addSeries parameter, but I can't get it to show more than two values. Any ideas?

[1]http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t1Yo3yafNIUctKXlErIz?p=preview) with the solution you are looking for...with key code additions below:

```
var names = myChart.addSeries(["name"], dimple.plot.bar);
myChart.addLegend(10, 50, 510, 20, "middle", [names]);
```